# Bringing separate asynchronous branches back into one branch again

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback

I am working on a node js app which makes use of the express and mysql libraries.

I have a MySQL user table with the following columns:

- auto incrementing primary id
- username varchar unique

There is no password, etc.

Other tables include:

room

- id
- room_name

user_room

- id
- user_id (FK to user table)
- room_id (FK to room table)

details

- id
- user_room_id (FK to user_room table)
- col1
- col2
- col3

Upon trying to connect to a room, I want the database to try pulling their data for that room.

If the data does not exist, I want to see if the username exists in the user table.

- If the username does exist, I want to get their id.
- If the username does not exist, I want to add their name to the user table and capture the last inserted id

Once having their id, I want to add a record to the user_room table for that user and then several records to the details table based on the newly inserted id in the user_room table.

I seem to be getting into a tangled web going into so many layers.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
socket.on('enter room', function(data, callback){

    var sql = "select col1, col2, col3 from room JOIN user_room on room.id = user_room.room_id JOIN user on user_room.user_id = user.id JOIN details on user_room.id = details.user_room_id where username = ?";
    db_connection.query(sql, [socket.nickname], function (err, result) {

        if (err){
            console.log("ENTER ROOM DB ERROR: " + err);
            return;
        }

        if (!result.length){
            var sql = "select id from user where name = ?";

            db_connection.query(sql, [socket.nickname], function (err, result){
                if (err){
                    console.log("ENTER ROOM, SELECT ID DB ERROR: " + err);
                    return;
                }

                if (!result.length){
                    var sql = "insert into user (name) values (?)";

                    db_connection.query(sql, [socket.nickname], function(err, result){
                        if (err){
                            console.log("ENTER ROOM, INSERT ID DB ERROR: " + err);
                            return;
                        }

                        id = result.insertId;

                    });
                }
                else {
                    id = result[0].id;
                }

            });

            //We need to pull things back into one branch again here    
            //Using the user id and room id I will insert a record into the user_room table
            //Then using the newly inserted id in the user_room table, I need to add records to a details table


        }
    });

     //Send col1, col2, and col3 data back to user
     //This section here also needs to be pulled back into one branch again
     io.sockets.emit('details', result);
});
```

It mostly works, but because I branch off in two different ways to get the user id (one if it already exists, and one if I need to insert it), I do not know how to pull it back together again into one branch.

What can I do to pull my code back into one branch again so that I can use the id again? Or, is there a better way of approaching this altogether?

A side question: Can I safely remove the "callback" in my opening function, or should I be using this somewhere in my code? I feel that the emit is like a callback to the client so that I do not need "callback" here.

Comment: Declare a function that takes `id` as a parameter, and then call that function when the `id` is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to get `userId` on `upsert`. I used `promise` to send the room data immediately, if available.

```
socket.on('enter room', function (data, callback) {
  let nickName = '';
  let roomId = '';

  return bookingDetails(nickName).then((details) => {
    if (details.length !== 0) {
      return Promise.resolve(details);
    } else {
      return createRoom(nickName, roomId);
    }
  }).then((details) => {
    io.sockets.emit('details', details);
  });
});

function createRoom(nickName, roomId) {
  return getUserDetails(nickName).then((userId) => {
    return insertUserRoom(userId, roomId); //your function
  }).then((userRoomDetails) => {
    return insertDetails(userRoomDetails); //your function
  });
}

function bookingDetails(nickName) {
  let sql = "select col1, col2, col3 from room " +
    "JOIN user_room on room.id = user_room.room_id " +
    "JOIN user on user_room.user_id = user.id " +
    "JOIN details on user_room.id = details.user_room_id where username = ?";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db_connection.query(sql, [nickName], function (err, details) {
      if (err) {
        return reject("ENTER ROOM DB ERROR: ");
      }
      return resolve(details);
    });
  });
}

function getUserDetails(nickName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let sql = "select id from user where name = ?";
    db_connection.query(sql, [nickName], function (err, userDetail) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      if (userDetail === null) { //insert
        return createUser(nickName);
      }
      return userDetail;
    }).then((userDetail) => {
      return resolve(userDetail.id);
    });
  });
}

function createUser(nickName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let sql = "insert into user (name) values (?)";
    db_connection.query(sql, [nickName], function (err, userDetail) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(userDetail);
    });
  });
}
```